# Vercel Serverless Functions Test before going into deployment

Tags: next.js, serverless, vercel

Is there a way to test Vercel serverless functions before I deploy.
I have tried to keep within the given restrictions of a hobby package, but would like to run them and see if there is any issues before I start to deploy.

I have run next build, but I assume this is still using my local machine.

Is the best way just to build a branch (one other than main) to Vercel?

Comment: You can use the preview environment in Vercel. See https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/environments#preview.

Comment: Thanks for the link, the fact it does not index with search engines is cool, so i suppose building to Vercel is the best way.